# TextBox , different ControlTemplate + IsEnabled

Tags: wpf, textbox, controltemplate

I have added a `style` to a `textbox`, where in I modify the `ControlTemplate` of the `textBox`.
I end up having a different `control template` for the `textbox`.
But I have a problem.
When I set the `IsEnabled` property to false, the normal textbox, is just `greyed` out.
But the one with different control template, still remains `white`.

Is there something specific I need to add as a part of `control template`, in order to obtain the default behavior?

thanks
Sandeep

Update -> Added the control template.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type commonControls:DerivedTextBox}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                    CornerRadius="2"
                    Padding="2"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                    x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have replaced the default XAML that makes the `TextBox` 'grayed out' when `IsEnabled` is set to `False`. If you want to replace this functionaluity, you will need to copy that part of the original `ControlTemplate`, which you can find at the [`TextBox Styles and Templates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068.aspx) page on MSDN.

In the default `ControlTemplate`, you will see a `VisualState` with the name `Disabled`... that is what you need, but you may as well copy most of the `VisualState`s from there.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlLightColor}" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: I shall try that out ! thanks man.. once again you came to my rescue !

Comment: I tried out the color, but the problem is, I am not able to match the color scheme of the default textbox, is there something wrong which I have done. ?

Comment: I have updated the question with my template, also the border seems to be different while disabled, I have no clues, on how to fix these!

Comment: On the linked page, you will find two sections containing XAML code. The first is the `ControlTemplate` and the second contains the `Resources` used in the `ControlTemplate`... you need to copy those and paste them into your `Resources` section.

Comment: as far as I can see, the `ControlTemplate` Section uses only two background colors from the resources, both of which I have included in the resources section.

Comment: What you can do is to (temporarily) remove your code and implement the whole default `ControlTemplate` from that page. Then, when it is all working correctly, just substitute your code for the relevant section(s) and it should all work fine.